# Inifinispan jgroups for different CacheModes

Tags: java, caching, infinispan

I've just started to work with Infinispan and don't know really much about jgroups. That's why I have worked with the default jgroups configuration so far.
Infinispan provides two default jgroups files `default-jgroups-tcp.xml` and `default-jgroups-udp.xml`. The Infinispan User Guide says that the tcp file should be used for distribution mode and the udp file for replication and invalidation. 
But in my application I'm able to dynamcally create new caches in different CacheModes. I can only set one jgroups file in the GlobalConfiguration of the CacheManager. So which file should I use or should I write my own one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either (but not both at the same time). You can only see the advantage of UDP multicast with replicated caches and larger cluster sizes (> 10).